# Is there an SQL query where we apply a set of conditions separately for each id?

Tags: mysql, sql

Eg. If we have a table like this exam_score (record_date refers to month when record is taken, Jan = 1, Feb = 2 etc):

| student | country | score | record_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | US | 70 | 1 |
| 2 | US | 60 | 2 |
| 3 | US | 80 | 3 |
| 4 | IT | 60 | 2 |
| 5 | IT | 100 | 4 |
| 6 | BR | 80 | 5 |

Which SQL query allows me to generate a table where, for each student, we obtain the highest score obtained by fellow students in the same country before him?

So in this case, I should have something like

| student | country | score | record_date | max_score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | US | 70 | 1 | null (no usa students before him) |
| 2 | US | 60 | 2 | 70 (among students before him, top score is 70) |
| 3 | US | 80 | 3 | 70 (among students before him, top score is 70) |
| 4 | IT | 60 | 2 | null (no italy students before him) |
| 5 | IT | 100 | 4 | 60 |
| 6 | BR | 80 | 5 | null |

Currently my workaround is to use Python together with SQL queries to get what I want, but could we do this with SQL alone? I'm using MySQL, but maybe the database doesn't matter in terms of the SQL query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have SELECT in the column:

```
select s.*,
    (select max(score)
     from students
     where country = s.country
     and record_date < s.record_date) as max_score
from students s
order by record_date
```

Comment: as a note to the OP, this can help him a lot to get started, but it's only the start of his solution. to get to the desired solution he would still need to do some work. amazing answer though.

Comment: @Demeteor forgotten the country wasn't it?

Comment: I mean he would need to make some variables to get his desired text. for example for the 70 in score table he needs to put it in a variable  
select @var = score from table ,  and then place this in the new column max_score along side the text his wants.
but also he would need a case to archive that part. I might be wrong though.. I misunderstand the questions offten

Comment: I see, and ok think I understand @Demeteor, following this train of thought I can add in country = s.country in the subquery. Really appreciate the help!

Edit: Just to clarify, the text beside 70 was not supposed to be in the table, it's to facilitate understanding for my qn. Couldve left it outside the table though, my bad.

Comment: @Joop Eggen did all the work !

Answer (score 2):

**Schema (MySQL v8.0)**

```
CREATE TABLE exam_score
    (`student` int, `country` varchar(2), `score` int, `record_date` int)
;
    
INSERT INTO exam_score
    (`student`, `country`, `score`, `record_date`)
VALUES
    (1, 'US', 70, 1),
    (2, 'US', 60, 2),
    (3, 'US', 80, 3),
    (4, 'IT', 60, 2),
    (5, 'IT', 100, 4),
    (6, 'BR', 80, 5)
;
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT student
     , country
     , score
     , record_date
     , MAX(lag_score) OVER (PARTITION BY country ORDER BY record_date) AS max_score
FROM (
  SELECT student
       , country
       , record_date
       , score
       , LAG(score) OVER (PARTITION BY country ORDER BY record_date) AS lag_score
  FROM exam_score
  ) a
ORDER BY student;
```

Output:

| student | country | score | record_date | max_score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | US | 70 | 1 |  |
| 2 | US | 60 | 2 | 70 |
| 3 | US | 80 | 3 | 70 |
| 4 | IT | 60 | 2 |  |
| 5 | IT | 100 | 4 | 60 |
| 6 | BR | 80 | 5 |  |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/a4DQ9mBPPsL8J5DLi52mQa/1)